# Weblogic libraries it is shipped with

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

Given I have WebLogic Server Version: 12.1.3.0.0

How can I find with which libraries, jars it ships with?

I'd like to figure out what to specify in `weblogic.xml` in `<prefer-application-packages>`, e.g.:

```
<container-descriptor>
    <prefer-web-inf-classes>false</prefer-web-inf-classes>
    <prefer-application-packages>
        <package-name>org.slf4j.*</package-name>
    </prefer-application-packages>
</container-descriptor>
```

Comment: You should be able to see a list of installed libraries by going to the weblogic console and selecting 'deployments'.

Comment: I can see there only my deployed application, but not weblogic's libraries

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following app for classloader filtering. Its shipped with weblogic server and available from the adminserver.

http://yourhost:yourport/wls-cat

example:
http://localhost:7001/wls-cat/